# Can I synthesize 4-aminophenol and/or acetic anhydride at home?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am going to try to synthesize acetaminophen as a possible science fair project, or just for fun, but doing it with precursors to the precursors of it might be more fun for myself then just using the easy to find things, but I couldn’t find any easy ways to synthesize either 4-aminophenol or acetic anhydride. So if anybody knows of methods of doing so that I could do at home, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: For your product: https://prepchem.com/synthesis-of-4-aminophenol/ For its precursor: https://www.prepchem.com/synthesis-of-phenylhydroxylamine/ Two-step synthesis starting from nitrobenzene. You will need zinc, ammonium chloride, sulfuric acid and sodium bicarbonate.

Comment: Chemistry should be done in an appropriate laboratory setting, with a fume hood and proper protective equipment.

Comment: I just don't think you could do it at home or maybe even school lab.

Answer (score 2):

Commenters already provided the main points to your question. So, I am providing some more info. to make it into an answer.

@TheRelentlessNucleophile already provided the [prepchem article](https://prepchem.com/synthesis-of-4-aminophenol/) for synthesizing 4-aminophenol [phenylhydroxylamine + sulfuric acid (for phenylhydroxylamine precursor, [you need nitrobenzene, zinc and ammonium chloride](https://www.prepchem.com/synthesis-of-phenylhydroxylamine/). If you don't have nitrobenzene, you can make it by nitrating benzene)]. For acetic anhydride, [you need acetyl chloride and sodium acetate.](https://www.prepchem.com/synthesis-of-acetic-anhydride/). Once you have these two reagents, you can make acetaminophen (paracetamol). I recommend to watch this [NileRed's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8Y3_7psygU) (taken from 6-part series of converting aspirin pills to paracetamol).

Again I am stressing what @Zhe said. Please do your experiments in a proper laboratory settings, with fume hoods or proper protective equipments. Do not do any kind of such experiments if you are not experienced in handling chemicals or don't know what you are doing. If you are doing for your science fair project, I recommend to take help from a person who is experienced in handling chemicals.

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but the days of swashbuckling, cavalier chemists are over. We're professionals now, with professional standards for safety and environmental awareness. Gone are the days of doing chemistry without goggles or characterizing your product as "having the characteristic taste of brucine."